# AWT token generating similar token

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, jwt

why is the algorithm returning the same token when I issue to generate a new token at each 10 millisecond

```
// generate a token every 10ms        

@Scheduled(fixedRate=10)
public void work() {
    // get user information
    UserProfile newuser = new UserProfile("abc", "abc123");

    //generate the token 
    String jwt = tokenProvider.generateToken(newuser);

    // print the token                           
    System.out.println(jwt);
}
```

the same token returned if I issue a new token in less than 1000 millisecond

Comment: what jwt library are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you aren't changing anything else, the issued time probably isn't measured down below a second by default.

I would add a token uuid to each token to differentiate the generated token string.